# NLog extension in dotnet core without nlog.config

Tags: .net-core, nlog, .net-7.0

I'm using NLog in a ASP.NET Core project, configured in code instead of using a `nlog.config` file. As described here:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code

I want to use the `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` extension, but can't find a way of using it when configuring in code.  All examples I've see involve using a nlog.config, add adding this in the XML:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

My code to do the config is this..

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

// add rules, targets is working fine...

var dbTarget = new DatabaseTarget();
// ... database config - removed
config.AddTarget("database", dbTarget);

var dbRule = new LoggingRule("*", loggingSettings.LogLevel, dbTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(dbRule);

LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

I want something like this, but no luck:

```
config.AddExtention("NLog.Web.AspNetCore")
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NLog Fluent Config](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API) like this with NLog v5:

```cs
NLog.LogManager.Setup()
    .SetupExtensions(e => e.RegisterNLogWeb())
    .LoadConfiguration(c => {
       c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(loggingSettings.LogLevel).WriteTo(dbTarget);
    });
```